Add additional jars / dependencies to a spring boot bootable jar
Is there a way to include additional dependencies or jar file in a Spring bootable jar?
I'm using the spring-boot-maven-plugin outside of a spring project to generate a bootable jar. This works fine, except the project also generates a jar file (not classes) that need to be included in the bootable jar as well.
The plugin's includes configuration parameter seems to filter the existing dependency set instead of adding to it.
The includeSystemScope won't work, because if I declare the dependency with scope system it needs to present at compile it. Which it is not (in that phase). Scope provided could work, but won't be picked up by the includeSystemScope.
Is there a way to add an additional jar file to the bootable jar?

How could providedwork. It signals that the respective dependency is provided by other means. But seriously, this sounds like an XY problem. Why not simply generate said jars in a different project, declare your plain old dependency in the project with the executable JAR and Bob's your uncle.

That did not work because the generated jars were not included as they are not part of the dependencies. I ended up moving the quarkus build to prepare-package and then immediately an unzip of the generated jars into classes. The maven-jar-plugin then included all of them in the jar.
